# My program returning the set_intersection value of two text files containing 479k words each is really slow. Is it my code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sorting, boost, set-intersection

I wrote a program to compare two text files containing all of the words in the dictionary (one forwards and one backwards). The idea is that when the text file containing all of the backwards words is compared with the forwards words, any matches will indicate that those words can be spelled both forwards and backwards and will return all palindromes as well as any words that spell both a word backwards and forwards.

The program works and I've tested it on three different file sizes. The first set contain only two words, just for testing purposes. The second contains 10,000 English words (in each text file), and the third contains all English words (~479k words). When I run the program calling on the first set of text files, the result is almost instantaneous. When I run the program calling on the set of text files containing 10k words, it takes a few hours. However, when I run the program containing the largest files (479k words), it ran for a day and returned only about 30 words, when it should have returned thousands. It didn't even finish and was nowhere near finishing (and this was on a fairly decent gaming PC).

I have a feeling it has to do with my code. It must be inefficient.

**There are two things that I've noticed:**

1. When I run: `cout << "token: " << *it << std::endl;` it runs endlessly on a loop forever and never stops. Could this be eating up processing power?
2. I commented out sorting because all my data is already sorted. I noticed that the second I did this, the program running 10,000 word text files sped up.

**However, even after doing these things there seemed to be no real change in speed in the program calling on the largest text files. Any advice? I'm kinda new at this. Thanks~**

*Please let me know if you'd like a copy of the text files and I'd happily upload them. Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
typedef boost::char_separator<char> separator_type;

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main()
{
    fstream file1; //fstream variable files
    fstream file2; //fstream variable files
    string dictionary1;
    string dictionary2;
    string words1; 
    string words2;

    dictionary1 = "Dictionary.txt";
    // dictionary1 = "Dictionarytenthousand.txt";
    // dictionary1 = "Twoworddictionary.txt"; //this dictionary contains only two words separated by a comma as a test 
    dictionary2 = "Backwardsdictionary.txt";
    // dictionary2 = "Backwardsdictionarytenthousand.txt";
    // dictionary2 = "Backwardstwoworddictionary.txt"; //this dictionary contains only two words separated by a comma as a test
    
    file1.open(dictionary1.c_str()); //opening Dictionary.txt
    file2.open(dictionary2.c_str()); //opening Backwardsdictionary.txt

    if (!file1)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file1"; //terminate with error
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!file2)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file2"; //terminate with error
        exit(1);
    }

    while (getline(file1, words1))
    {
        while (getline(file2, words2))
        {
            boost::tokenizer<separator_type> tokenizer1(words1, separator_type(",")); //separates string in Twoworddictionary.txt into individual words for compiler (comma as delimiter)            

            auto it = tokenizer1.begin();
            while (it != tokenizer1.end())
            {
                std::cout << "token: " << *it << std::endl; //test to see if tokenizer works before program continues              

                vector<string> words1Vec; // vector to store Twoworddictionary.txt strings in              
                words1Vec.push_back(*it++); // adds elements dynamically onto the end of the vector 
                
                boost::tokenizer<separator_type> tokenizer2(words2, separator_type(",")); //separates string in Backwardstwoworddictionary.txt into individual words for compiler (comma as delimiter) 
               
                auto it2 = tokenizer2.begin();
                while (it2 != tokenizer2.end())
                {
                    std::cout << "token: " << *it2 << std::endl; //test to see if tokenizer works before program continues
                    
                    vector<string> words2Vec; //vector to store Backwardstwoworddictionary.txt strings in                 
                    words2Vec.push_back(*it2++); //adds elements dynamically onto the end of the vector 
                    
                    vector<string> matchingwords(words1Vec.size() + words2Vec.size()); //vector to store elements from both dictionary text files (and ultimately to store the intersection of both, i.e. the matching words)                   

                    //sort(words1Vec.begin(), words1Vec.end()); //set intersection requires its inputs to be sorted                 
                    //sort(words2Vec.begin(), words2Vec.end()); //set intersection requires its inputs to be sorted
                    
                    vector<string>::iterator it3 = set_intersection(words1Vec.begin(), words1Vec.end(), words2Vec.begin(), words2Vec.end(), matchingwords.begin()); //finds the matching words from both dictionaries                 

                    matchingwords.erase(it3, matchingwords.end());  

                    for (vector<string>::iterator it4 = matchingwords.begin(); it4 < matchingwords.end(); ++it4) cout << *it4 << endl; // returns matching words                                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    file1.close();
    file2.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted does not do what you say it does.  What is the file format?

Comment: Why do you `getline()` every line in `file2` for each line you read out of `file1` ?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The file format is .sln if that's what you mean

Comment: @JeremyFriesner That's a mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Stop using namespace.  Type the extra stuff.

Have code do one thing.  Your code isn't doing what you claim it does, probably becuase you are doing 4 things at once and getting confused.

Then glue the code together.

Getline supports arbitrary delimiters.  Use it with `','`.

Write code that converts a file into a vector of strings.

```
std::vector<std::string> getWords(std::string filename);
```

then test it works.  You are doing this wrong in your code posted above, in that you are making length 1 vectors and tossing them.

That will remove about half of your code.

Next, for `set_intersection`, use `std::back_inserter` and an empty vector as your output.  Like `(blah begin, blah end, foo begin, foo end, std::back_inserter(vec3))`.  It will call `push_back` with each result.

In pseudo code:

```
std::vec<std::string> loadWords(std::string filename)
  auto file=open(filename)
  std::vec<std::string> retval
  while(std::readline(file, str, ','))
    retval.push_back(str)
  return retval

std::vec<string> intersect(std::string file1, std::string file2)
  auto v1=loadWords(file1)
  auto v2=loadWords(file2)
  std::vec<string> v3;
  std::set_intersect(begin(v1),end(v1),begin(v2),end(v2),std::back_inserter(v3))
  return v3
```

and done.

Also stop it with the C++03 loops.

```
for(auto& elem:vec)
  std::cout<<elem<<'\n';
```

is far clearer and less error prone than manually futzing with iterators.

Comment: Hey, thank you! I will try this. I seriously appreciate it.

Comment: @maria9876 Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Why are you spamming out that on questions and answers?  I mean, sure, a checkmark, but honestly it is a week old question, if they don't want to push the checkmark, it is their business.  And "feel free to contact us"?  It is coming across a bit strange.